# Ошибка при использовании метода subscribe

Tags: angular

Есть такой класс в файле .ts.
Подчёркивается ошибка в методе subscribe - ошибка: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable'.ts(2339)

```
@Injectable()  
export class ProductRepository {  
private products: Product[] = [];  
private categories: string[] = [];  

constructor(private dataSource:   
StaticDataSource) {  

dataSource.getProducts.subscribe(data 
=> {  
        this.products = data;  
        this.categories = data.map(p =>    
p.category)  
        .filter((c, index, array) =>   
array.indexOf(c) ==index).sort();  
    });  
  }  
}
```

Также подчёркнут входной параметр data метода subscribe, p - метода map, а также все параметры метода filter.

```
import { Observable } from   
'rxjs/Observable';
```

Этот import тусклого цвета с таким предупреждением:
    Observable' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133).
Файл static.datasource.ts:

```
 import { Injectable } from   
 "@angular/core";  
import { Product } from   
"./product.model";  
import { Observable } from   
"rxjs/Observable";  
import "rxjs/add/observable/from";  

    @Injectable()  
    export class StaticDataSource {  
        private products: Product[] = [  
            new Product(1, "Product 1",   
"Category 1", "Product 1 (Category 1)",   
100),  
            new Product(2, "Product 2",   
"Category 1", "Product 2 (Category 1)",   
100),  
            new Product(3, "Product 3",   
"Category 1", "Product 3 (Category 1)",   
100),  
            new Product(4, "Product 4",   
"Category 1", "Product 4 (Category 1)",   
100),  
            new Product(5, "Product 5",   
"Category 1", "Product 5 (Category 1)",   
100)        
        ];  

        getProducts():   
Observable<Product[]> {  
            return           

Observable.from([this.products]);  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что вы не вызываете getProducts в подписке.
Вам нужно подписаться на возвращаемый ответ getProducts()

```
ngOnInit() {
  dataSource.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
       this.products = data;
       .....
  });
}
```

Comment: А где делать эту подписку? Я добавил метод в файл product.repository.ts перед конструктором, но у меня ошибка - Cannot find name 'dataSource'. Также подчёркнут входной параметр data - Параметр data неявно имеет тип any